# Converting dockerfile + bash script into OpenShift deployment config

Tags: docker, openshift

I have this dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest
COPY mongodb.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y mongodb-org mongodb-org-shell iproute nano

RUN mkdir -p /data/db && chown -R mongod:mongod /data
```

That I can build and run locally just fine with docker with:

```
docker build -t my-image .
docker run -t -d -p 27017:27017 --name my-container my-image
docker cp mongod.conf my-container:/etc/mongod.conf
docker exec -u mongod my-container "mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf"
```

Now I would like run the container in OpenShift. I have managed to build and push the image to a namespace. And have created the below **deploymentConfig** that runs the container - just like I can do locally.

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    name: my-app
    namespace: my-namespace
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      app: my-app
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: my-app
          deploymentconfig: my-app
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: ${IMAGE}
          command: ["mongod"]
          ports:
           - containerPort: 27017 
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

When I click deploy the image is pulled successfully but I get the error:

```
exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
```

Why does it not have read/write on the `/data/db` folder? As can be seen from above **Dockerfile** that folder is created and the **mongod** user is owner of that folder.

Is it necessary to grant the **mongod** user read/write on that folder in the deploymentConfig as well somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Docker files will run as an unknown, arbirtrary, non-root user (put simply imagine mongodb running as user `1000000001` but there is no guarantee that will be the number chosen). This may mean the `mongod` user is not the selected user causing these issues so [check the documentation](https://docs.okd.io/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html#use-uid) for guidelines of supporting Arbitrary User IDs.

   > For an image to support running as an arbitrary user, directories and files that may be written to by processes in the image should be **owned by the root group and be read/writable by that group**. Files to be executed should also have group execute permissions.
   >
   > Adding the following to your Dockerfile sets the directory and file permissions to allow users in the root group to access them in the built image:
   >
   > ```
   > RUN chgrp -R 0 /some/directory && \   <- Set the group to 0 (the root group)
   > chmod -R g=u /some/directory          <- Here you will set your permissions
   > ```
2. Your `mongod.conf` can be mounted as a [`ConfigMap`](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/configmaps.html) - an Openshift object often used to manage configuration that can be mounted as a (read only) volume

## Edit - Command explanation

1. `chgrp` vs `chown`

   `chown` is also perfectly fine to use here but as we are only interested in updating the "group", `chgrp` provides a little extra security to make sure that is the only thing that is changed (due to mistyped command etc.)
2. `chmod -R g=u`

   - `chmod` is used to change the file permissions;
   - `-R` tells it to recurse through the path (in case there are subdirectories they will also receive the same permissions);
   - `g=u` means "group=user" or "give the group the same permissions as those that are already there for the user"

Comment: Actually the error is not related to the mongo.conf file but instead the folder /data/db that mongodb write files to when it starts. So how to I make that folder read/write - since its not enough doing that in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @u123 You're right I was merely showing how the `DeploymentConfig` can be written to meet the requirements in your `Dockerfile`. Please read the documentation linked above on Arbitrary UIDs which explains how to set the permissions in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: That seems to solve my issue, thanks! Two questions: 1) What does chmod -R g=u actually do? I know chmod but was not able to find what 'g=u' does in: https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod. 2) Why use chgrp instead of chown?